# Facebook JSON not being displayed on TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, facebook, uitableview

I am trying to display Facebook JSON from a correctly authenticated account onto a TableView, however no information is displayed despite Json being logged. Here is how I am attempting to display the information onto the TableView:

```
- (void)fetchFacebookPosts {
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"%@",result);
            facebookResponse = [result mutableCopy];
            [self.facebookPosts addObjectsFromArray:result[@"data"]];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Failure: %@", error);
        }
    }];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    FacebookCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"FacebookCell"];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"]];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[FacebookCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"FacebookCell"];
    }

    NSDictionary *entry = facebookPosts[indexPath.row];

    // Set Image

    // Set User Name
    NSString *user =  entry[@"story"];
    [cell.textLabel setText:user];

    return cell;
}
```

In this code `facebookResponse` is a `NSMutableDictionary`
and `facebookPosts` is a `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: What is your `numberOfRowsInSection`?  Have you alloc/init the `self.facebookPosts` array?  You also need to reload the tableview from the main queue

Comment: @Paulw11 the `numberOfRowsInSection` is `facebookPosts.count` and by alloc/init I have @synthesize both `facebookPosts` and `facebookResult`

Comment: `@synthesize` isn't enough (or even necessary) - You need to allocate the `NSMutableArray` in somewhere like  `viewDidLoad` or it will be nil